# Installing NetBSD sets via HTTP on Raspberry PI fails

Tags: raspberry-pi, netbsd

I want to try NetBSD on my Raspberry PI B. I downloaded the NetBSD installer image for the RPI from [here](ftp://nyftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD-daily/HEAD/201412290640Z/evbarm-earm/binary/).

Unfortunately, I have some troubles installing the sets from the daily snapshot directory. I follows the advices given both in [1](http://box.matto.nl/netbsdraspberry.htmlhttp://box.matto.nl/netbsdraspberry.html) and [2](https://wiki.netbsd.org/ports/evbarm/raspberry_pi/).
As suggested I used http with the following configuration:

```
 Your disk is now ready for installing the kernel and the distribution sets.
 As noted in your INSTALL notes, you have several options.  For ftp or nfs,
 you must be connected to a network with access to the proper machines.

 Sets selected 10, processed 0, Next set kern-RPI.

                          ┌─────────────────────────┐
                          │ Install from            │
                          │                         │
                          │ a: CD-ROM / DVD         │
                          │ b: FTP                  │
                          │>c: HTTP                 │
                          │ d: NFS                  │
                          │ e: Floppy               │
                          │ f: Unmounted fs         │
                          │ g: Local directory      │
                          │ h: Skip set             │
                          │ i: Skip set group       │
                          │ j: Abandon installation │
                          └─────────────────────────┘
 The following are the http site, directory, user, and password that will be
 used.  If "user" is "ftp", then the password is not needed.

>a: Host                      nyftp.NetBSD.org
 b: Base directory            pub/NetBSD-daily/HEAD/201412290640Z
 c: Binary set directory      /evbarm-arm/binary/sets
 d: Source set directory      /source/sets
 e: User                      ftp
 f: Password
 g: Proxy
 h: Transfer directory        /usr/INSTALL
 i: Delete after install      No
 j: Configure network
 k: Exit
 x: Get Distribution
```

The network configuration has been defined as follows:

```
 DNS Domain:             Speedport_W_504V_Typ_A
 Host Name:              rpi
 Nameserver:             192.168.2.1    
 Primary Interface:      usmsc0
 Media type:             autoselect
 Host IP:                192.168.2.106
 Netmask:                255.255.255.0
 IPv4 Gateway:           192.168.2.1
```

I checked these values for correctness on my local PC, see:

```
nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 192.168.2.102/24, gw = 192.168.2.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.2.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          Speedport_W_504V_Typ_A
```

My network setup is as follows:
Internet ----- DSL Router (192.168.2.1.) --- PC (192.168.2.102), Raspberry PI (192.168.2.106).

The output from the sysinst is as follows:

```
     Status: Command failed                                                     
    Command: /usr/bin/ftp -a http://nyftp.NetBSD.org/pub/NetBSD-daily/HEAD/20141
2290640Z/evbarm-arm/binary/sets/kern-RPI.tgz                                    
     Hit enter to continue                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ftp: Can't LOOKUP `nyftp.NetBSD.org:http': Temporary failure in name resolution
```

The Ethernet cable is connected and a valid IP has been assigned via DHCP (I am connected to the RPI via SSH).

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!
Jo

Answer (score 1):

The hint of Mr. Eric Schnoebelen finally brought me to the following work around:
Instead of using the hostname (nyftp.netbsd.org) I used the IP address which I looked up using nslookup on my local PC:

```
nslookup nyftp.netbsd.org
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
nyftp.netbsd.org    canonical name = netbsd3.cs.columbia.edu.
Name:   netbsd3.cs.columbia.edu
Address: 128.59.23.63
```

This finally worked...